# C# Windows Formsで同じプロセス名で特定の引数が同じ場合の2重起動防止方法は？

Tags: c#, winforms

掲題の件、C#で同じWindows Formsのexeで特定の引数が同じ場合に2重起動を防止したいのですが
可能でしょうか？

例) 「A.exe argA argB」を起動中に以下の要件を満たしたい。
A.exe argC argD は、起動OK
A.exe argA argE は、起動NG

引数は必ず指定されるものとします。引数が不足している場合は、起動エラーにします。
arg[0]が文字列として完全一致した場合に、2重起動を抑止したいです。

具体的な、要件ですが、Windows Formsの画面をメニューから
同じランチャ(A.exe）を使って、異なるForm画面を起動しようとしています。
（A.exeが異なる引数で複数のプロセスとして起動することになります。）
その際に、同じアプリコードの画面の場合に起動を抑止したいです。

何かアドバイス頂ければと思います。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 引数を名前にしてmutex作るとか？
.netでmutex使った事ないので、確実にできると断言できませんが。。。

Comment: 特定の引数とは `args[0]` が同じ、でいいんですか？ `ArgA` が指定されずに起動されたらどうします？　あと同じとは文字列として完全一致のことでしょうか？それとも例えば大文字小文字は区別せず同じとか、ファイル名として同じとか？実際にコード化するには仕様が不完全です。もうちょっと案件定義をきっちりして追記してくれると幸いです。

Comment: EXE ファイル名を名前にして mutex 作って排他ならやったことがありますしうまくいきます。この案件の場合 `ファイル名 + args[0]` （のハッシュ結果）を mutex 名にすると良いのでは？ `mutex` が GC されないように「ローカル変数にしない」工夫は必要です。でもたいていは単に多重起動しないだけでなくて、すでに起動している EXE に `args` を渡して処理を委任したくなりますから、もう一工夫必要かも。

Comment: 条件がまだ不足しているでしょう。例で2つ目の引数が同じとなるA.exe argF argBの場合はどうなるか、とか。色々と条件が増えるようなら、起動管理用の別プログラムを用意するのが近道です。

Comment: 全ての引数名でそれぞれmutex作れば良いだけの話ではと思ったんですが、exe本体の二重起動は別に制御したくないんですよね？起動時に全てのmutex取れなければNGで良いような？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

他プロセスのコマンドライン引数はWMIで取得できますので、起動時に排他をかけつつ値を検証すればよいのでは。

```
[STAThread]
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var cp = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    Console.WriteLine($"PID:{cp.Id}");
    for (var i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($" - {i}: {args[i]}");
    }

    var mutex = new Mutex(false, typeof(Program).FullName);

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entering Mutex");
        mutex.WaitOne();

        var pn = cp.ProcessName + ".exe";

        using (var mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Process"))
        {
            foreach (var op in mc.GetInstances())
            {
                if (pn.Equals(op["Name"] as string, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var pid = Convert.ToInt32(op["ProcessId"]);

                    if (pid == cp.Id)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    var cmd = op["CommandLine"] as string;

                    // TODO:コマンドライン引数は""でエスケープできるのできちんと解析する必要がある
                    var otherArgs = cmd.Split(' ')
                                        // 先頭は実行ファイルのため飛ばす
                                        .Skip(1)
                                        .ToArray();

                    Console.WriteLine($"PID:{pid}");
                    for (var i = 0; i < otherArgs.Length; i++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($" - {i}: {otherArgs[i]}");
                    }

                    // 引数が被っていたら終了
                    if (args.Intersect(otherArgs).Any())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Already exists");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
    finally
    {
        mutex.ReleaseMutex();
        Console.WriteLine("Exit Mutex");
    }

    // TODO: 実際の起動処理を入れる。
    // Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    // Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    // Application.Run(new Form1());
    Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit...");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: 試させて頂きます。